# COPY JSON formatted CSV Lines into Temp Table in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, csv, jdbi

I have a CSV file which each line is a JSON and to be copied into a temp table.

Temp table is created by:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table(json_rec jsonb) ON COMMIT DROP;
```

Each records in this table will be copied into another temp table but this is another topic.

Lines look like:

```
{"id":300762,"name":"Ik wil buiten","short_name":"Ik wil buiten","exceptions":[{"type_id":3},{"type_id":3},{"type_id":4}]}
{"id":300762,"name":"Ik \"wil\" buiten","short_name":"Ik wil buiten","exceptions":[{"type_id":3},{"type_id":3},{"type_id":4}]}
```

These lines can have escaped double quotes as the second line.

To copy these lines into the temp table I invoke the method of postgres library:

```
public long copyIn(final String sql, InputStream from) throws SQLException, IOException {
    return copyIn(sql, from, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

with query

```
COPY temp_table FROM STDIN
```

and csv file as inputstream

It throws PSQLException:

> invalid input syntax for type json   Detail: Token "wil" is invalid.

So, since the default mode is JSON, escaped double quotes break the json format. I change the method into CSV by:

```
COPY temp_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV
```

Now, the "," delimiter is problematic so I change it by

```
COPY temp_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER '|'
```

Now, it throws another PSQLException:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
> Detail: Token "id" is invalid.

Apparently it switches into JSON mode again.

How can I copy these JSON formatted lines in CSV file into a temporary table ?

Comment: That is not a CSV file.

Comment: @jjanes, it is in a .csv file. Data does not contain a header.

Comment: Naming your dog "cow" does not turn it into a cow.

Comment: This isn't csv, you don't want to Separate between columns, not even on a Comma. What happens when you use WITH (FORMAT TEXT) ?

Comment: @jjanes, you are right but this is the case, I cannot change the file extension or data format in the file.

Comment: It is not a CSV file, each line in the file is JSON. Escaped double quotes don't break JSON as demonstrated by this query:
`WITH input (line) AS (VALUES ($$ {"id" :300762, "name" :"Ik wil buiten", "short_name" :"Ik wil buiten", "exceptions" :[{"type_id" :3 }, {"type_id" :3 }, {"type_id" :4 }]}$$), ($$ {"id" :300762, "name" :"Ik \"wil\" buiten", "short_name" :"Ik wil buiten", "exceptions" :[{"type_id" :3 }, {"type_id" :3 }, {"type_id" :4 }]}$$)) SELECT (line::jsonb) -> 'name' FROM input;`

Comment: The problem is that `\` is seen as an escape character in the reader process, so `\"wil\"` becomes `"wil"` before the COPY process sees the input text. This can be demonstrated by the following: `COPY temp_table FROM PROGRAM $$sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' /tmp/test_file.txt$$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the two lines we can see, the only special (to the COPY) character in the data is the newline character.  Every thing else should be taken literally, including commas, double quotes and backslashes (all of which are then special to JSON, but must not be to COPY). Unfortunately there is no direct way to tell COPY to do this. You will need to assign the special characters to be ones that don't appear in your data set. Since the escape character cannot be changed from `\` in text mode you need to abuse the CSV mode to do this.  Assuming neither tab nor backspace appear in your data, that would leave you with something like this:

```
copy temp_table from stdin with (format csv, quote E'\t', delimiter E'\b');
```

Comment: This one worked! In my csv file, there are just texts between quotes so this answer might be accurate. Could you elaborate the answer for the beginners in postgres like me with the detail like what is 'E' used for ?

Comment: @GaripTipici: From the manual: An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: Without the E, the '\t' and '\b' would each represent a literal backslash followed by another character.  the 'E' means they instead represent control characters tab and backspace.  It is like the `-e` switch of the Linux `echo` command, if you are familiar with that.